# Create and Manipulate SVG in Vue project

Tags: jquery, svg, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and need to create a Vue component to create and manipulate SVG.  From my understanding it's not best to use JQuery in a Vue component.  However I would like to because it's so straightforward to select elements.

Here is my Vue component, but I'm not sure how to make it functional.  (Note: the SVG will be coming from a web service so I need to append it to the DOM programmatically.)

```
<div id="app">
  <p>Hover mouse over the lights to turn them on.</p>
  <p>(How do I make this work??)</p>
  <div id="svg-div" v-html="svg" />
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    svg: `
      <svg width="50" height="120">
          <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="120" style="fill:black" />
          <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="15" fill="red" opacity=".3"/>
          <circle cx="30" cy="65" r="15" fill="yellow" opacity=".3"/>
          <circle cx="30" cy="100" r="15" fill="lightgreen" opacity=".3"/>
      </svg>`
  }
})
```

Here is a working example (non Vue) using JQuery.

```js
var svg = `
<svg width="50" height="120">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="120" style="fill:black" />
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="15" fill="red" opacity=".3"/>
  <circle cx="30" cy="65" r="15" fill="yellow" opacity=".3"/>
  <circle cx="30" cy="100" r="15" fill="green" opacity=".3"/>
</svg>
`;

$('#svg-div').html(svg);

$('circle').mouseenter(function() {
 $(this).attr('opacity', '1');
});

$('circle').mouseleave(function() {
 $(this).attr('opacity', '.3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover mouse over the lights to turn them on.</p>
<div id="svg-div" />
```

Comment: You're correct, jQuery and Vue don't mix well together, because Vue's approach is to (almost) never manipulate the dom yourself, but let the vue renderer do the work for you while you only have to worry about data. From what you describe, what you want to achieve in this example is easily done with css and it'd be more declarative. Is there anything that speaks against using css in this case? (See this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEMwbg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just directly bind the parts of the svg that you want to be dynamic. [Here is a simple tutorial](https://travishorn.com/vue-svg-2310f1b151d4). You need to get the 'markup' of your svg out of javascript variables and into a template element.

**[Here's a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ugb6c)**. Note that you can even animate your svg with CSS. Not bad, eh?

Here's what one of your dynamic circle elements looks like...

```
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="15" fill="red" :opacity="redO" @mouseenter="redO = 1" @mouseleave="redO = .3"/>
```

Your requirement to load the svg via webservice will complicate things. It's not the loading - the challenge is to inject the bindings into the source of the svg. You can do this with Dom methods and [setAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp). setAttribute() will let you set whatever attributes you like, starting with : and @, so you're essentially transforming your svg into a vue template with javascript. This code will be brittle, and vulnerable to changes in the structure of the svg, but it will get you out of a hole. You need to do all the attribute injecting before you initialize Vue

Comment: Marking this as the answer since you did answer the question about how to make it work with Vue.  But your point is correct, since I can't modify the SVG then it won't work for me, but appreciate the insight.

Comment: Did you try injecting bindings with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simple-svg), that will inline an svg for you, and give you access to some basic properties. It won't do everything you need, but it looks to be a very useful start.