# How to bind data property to dynamic elements?

Tags: vue.js

After the page is loaded, the content of a SVG file will be injected to the page. How can I bind a data property to an element in the SVG to do something like this:

```
<g :data-type="type">...</g>
```

or this:

```
<g :class="{ active: isActive }">...</g>
```

Does Vue provide a way to do dynamic binding?

Comment: Are the SVG elements populated dynamically (from sort of API), or just some properties that needs to be binded such as `type`, `isActive` ?

Comment: @Belmin Bedak the SVG elements are injected from the file via SVGInjector https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector. And I need some elements to have binding instead of manually manipulate them via query selector.

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this came up yesterday.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769524/1585345) You want to be able to transform a source over which you have no control into a template for Vue, by scripting the bindings. I think the easiest way out of this will be to inject your bindings into your svg using [setAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattributenode.asp) before initialising Vue. This works marvelously. setAttribute() does not validate your attribute, and doesn't care if it starts with : or @, so go for it.