# Vue.js binding events to SVG image elements

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

I'm looking for an option to bind Vue.js directives to elements in SVG. For example I have SVG image created in inkscape, key elements of this image have ids

```
<svg>
  ...
  <g id="layer 1" inkscape:label="layer 1">
    ...
    <g id="active_element1">
      <img inkscape:export-filename="important_element1.png">
```

I was able to load SVG with vue-svg-loader as a component, but it doesn't consider what is inside SVG. I also tried to add directives to SVG in inkscape and load as plain text to  tag, but then Vue needs some kind of recompile.
Is there a prettier way to get to elements inside SVG?

Comment: [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simple-svg) package promises to do what you need . [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046994/1585345) question might be interesting

Comment: vue-simple-svg is promissing, but sadly even now it can't draw complicated image, fillColor and strokeColor aren't supported yet

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using anime.js, I also work with vue js and for animations use anime.jsi